# how to use two different feeds on one drupal

Tags: views, feeds

I am using drupal.org/project/views_export_xls Views Excel export
[image]I added two different feeds to my drupal view , but only one of them (the second one) shows as an icon on the page , and if I remove the second one the first one shows up on the page.  how can I see both of them on the view page?

[image][image]

Comment: I found the answer, if I use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) instead of Views Export XLS , I am able to get two different views on the page

Comment: As a side note, you should look into the security updates to the site on priority. It is very important to keep the updates to avoid any loopholes which could be exploited.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to create a page view w/ two RSS icons with the following steps.

1. Create a view with a **page** display.

[image: Step 1]

2. Add a first "feed" display. You can customize what you want the feed to return here.

[image: Step 2]

3. Set a path for the first feed display.

[image: Step 3-1]

[image: Step 3-2]

4. Attach the first feed display to the "page" display.

[image: Step 4-1]

[image: Step 4-2]

5. Repeat steps 2-4 to create and attach a second feed display. It should look something like this.

[image: Step 5]

6. Save the view and view the page. There should be two separate feed icons.

[image: Step 8]

I hope this helps!

Comment: That is what I did but I get only one feed icon

Comment: And you attached them both to your page view like in step 4? Because I can't seem to duplicate your issue unless I actually remove the display. Two feed icons show up even if they don't have results. Can you modify your question to provide more detail on what you did?

Comment: I just added pictures of what I did, its the same exact thing as you except with XLS format and you can see I only get one icon.

Comment: Views doesn't have an option for XLS out of the box. It looks like you're using another module to get that. Do you know the module you're using? For the sake of debugging, can you switch over to the standard RSS feed and see if you get two icons?

Comment: i tried with standard RSS feed and got no icons at all!

Comment: I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls Views Excel export